# First date of first membership?

Tags: civimember

We have a system with multiple membership types - at renewal, people can switch between different membership types.

Is there a query or feature available to show the date of FIRST membership irregardless of the membership type that can be displayed within Drupal Views?

The "Create Date" doesn't work for us as people can register for events (before they become members) and therefore, this would not actually reflect first date of membership.

Comment: Alex - do your contacts maintain one membership record (which just changes type based on their selection each time), or is there one record for each membership type they've chosen over time?  If there's just one record, theoretically the join date on the membership record should work for your needs.

Comment: Hi Lesley, there would be multiple membership records (so situation 1). If it was situation 2, it would make things straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a smarter way to do this in Views, but the short version is: I would create a View that shows memberships, then create another view that shows contacts and in the latter pull in the former using [Views Field Views](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) (ie you can say, show me the results of the first view based on a match for the contact id in the second view. and set it to show only a single result per contact sorted by oldest first, and that 'should' get you what you want. Hopefully I haven't missed out too many critical steps.

Comment: Alex, pls help the health of StackExchange by updating